# Download table data from web using excel VBA

Tags: xml, excel, vba

I would like to download the table data from the website: http://stats.nba.com/teams/four-factors/#!?sort=TEAM_NAME&dir=1

1. I tried with excel feature: Data > From Web - it was not worked.
2. I've used the below code but nothing returned. - But it is working with other websites.

When we look on the pages using **"View Source"** the table data is not available but if we use **"Inspect Element"** the table data is available.

So, is there a way to look in **Inspect Element** on a web page and scrap the data using Excel VBA?

```
    Sub UsingXML()

    Dim XMLPage As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Dim HTMLDoc As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument

    XMLPage.Open "GET", "http://stats.nba.com/teams/four-factors/#!?sort=TEAM_NAME&dir=1", False
    XMLPage.send

    HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML = XMLPage.responseText

    ProcessHTMLPage HTMLDoc

    End Sub

    Sub ProcessHTMLPage(HTMLPage As MSHTML.HTMLDocument)

    Dim HTMLTable As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    Dim HTMLTables As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
    Dim HTMLRow As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    Dim HTMLCell As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    Dim RowNum As Long, ColNum As Integer

    Set HTMLTables = HTMLPage.getElementsByTagName("table")

    For Each HTMLTable In HTMLTables
    Worksheets.Add
    Range("A1").Value = HTMLTable.className
    Range("B1").Value = Now

    RowNum = 2
    For Each HTMLRow In HTMLTable.getElementsByTagName("tr")

        ColNum = 1
        For Each HTMLCell In HTMLRow.Children
            Cells(RowNum, ColNum) = HTMLCell.innerText
            ColNum = ColNum + 1
        Next HTMLCell

        RowNum = RowNum + 1
    Next HTMLRow

    Next HTMLTable

    End Sub
```

Could you please advise what is missing in this code. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried automating Internet Explorer instead?

Comment: I've tried with Internet Explorer. The problem is when I 'View Source' the table data is not showing whereas through "Inspect Element" the table data is available. The code above looks and get data from "View Source". Is there a way to get the data from "Inspect Element"?

Comment: Since I've misunderstood the question, I've deleted my answer.